# Almost all forms of String comparisons are not working in C++ 11

Tags: c++, string, c++11, boolean, comparison

So I am doing a school project that requires me to execute my program with arguments and display the contents of a file based on a particular action. 
This is done by simply requesting the action after the file name is specified.
It is:

./executable_name 'filename' 'action'

actions include **list** or **find**. **List** will list all the book contents of the specific file in that order and **find** will find a book by it's ISBN number specified.

Now my error lies with the **find** function, more specifically how i compare the Strings. I cannot compare the strings within the "find" function for the life of me. Ive tried "strcmp()" with the ".c_str()", I've tried "==", I've tried "string.copmare(string2)", and nothing. I have developed some interesting clues though.

If I try to print the string from my array of arguments concatenated with a few letters it properly does some expected printing, **BUT** if I perform the same action from the struct instance of any particular book array it seems to be overwritten like a return carriage type.

**EX:**

argv[4] = 0-201-60464-7 near here

books[0].isbn = near here-60464-7

Driver File

```
##include"book.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  //The structure of the book will also incorporate an array to
  //acommadate more books
    Book books[35];
    string filename = argv[1];
    int filesRead = read (filename, books);

    if(string(argv[2])== "list")
    {
  for(int index =0;index < filesRead; index++ )
  {
    cout << books[index].title << endl;
    cout << books[index].authorCount<< endl;
    for(int j =0; j < books[index].authorCount; j++)
     {
         cout << books[index].authors[j] << endl;
     }
     cout << books[index].publisher <<endl;
     cout << books[index].yearPublish <<endl;
     cout << books[index].hardcover << endl;
     cout << books[index].price << endl;
     cout << books[index].isbn << endl;
     cout << books[index].copies << endl;
   }
}
if(argc > 3)
{
  if(string(argv[2]) == "find")
  {
    int book_index = find(argv[3], books, filesRead);
    if(book_index < 0)
    {
      cout << "Not found" << endl;
    }
    cout << books[book_index].title << endl;
    cout << books[book_index].authorCount<< endl;
    for(int j =0; j < books[book_index].authorCount; j++)
     {
         cout << books[book_index].authors[j];
     }
     cout << books[book_index].publisher <<endl;
     cout << books[book_index].yearPublish <<endl;
     cout << books[book_index].hardcover << endl;
     cout << books[book_index].price << endl;
     cout << books[book_index].isbn << endl;
     cout << books[book_index].copies << endl;
     }
   }
}
```

Function file

```
#include"book.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;
int read (string filename, Book books[])
{
  ifstream inputFile(filename);
  //validation for the file itself
  if(!inputFile)
  {
    cout << "File does not exist!" << endl;
  }
  //use a mix of get line and ifstream
  //created a temporary string to consume lines
  //from primitive data types
  int counter =0;
  string consume_line;

  while(counter < 35 && getline(inputFile, books[counter].title))
  {
    inputFile >> books[counter].authorCount;
    getline(inputFile, consume_line);
      for(int j =0; j < books[counter].authorCount; j++)
       {
           getline(inputFile, books[counter].authors[j]);
       }
    getline(inputFile, books[counter].publisher);
    inputFile >> books[counter].yearPublish;
    inputFile >> books[counter].hardcover;
    inputFile >> books[counter].price;
    getline(inputFile, consume_line);
    getline(inputFile, books[counter].isbn);
    inputFile >> books[counter].copies;
    getline(inputFile, consume_line);
    if(inputFile.eof())
    {
      break;
    }
    counter++;
  }

   return counter;
}
int find(string id, Book books[], int length)
{
  int found=0;
  for(int index = 0; index < length; index++)
  {
    string test =books[index].isbn;
    if(id.compare(test)==0)
    {
      found = index;

      break;
    }
    if(id > test)
    {
      cout << "greater than" << endl;
      found = -1;
      break;
    }
    if(id < test)
    {
      cout << "less than" << endl;
      found =-1;
      break;

    }

  }
  return found;
}
```

Header File

```
// @file book.h
#ifndef BOOK_H
#define BOOK_H
#include <string>
using namespace std;
const int MAX_AUTHORS = 20;
struct Book {
 string title;
 string authors[MAX_AUTHORS];
 short authorCount;
 string publisher;
 short yearPublish;
 bool hardcover;
 float price;
 string isbn;
 long copies;
};
/**
* @param filename name of the input data file
* @param books[] an array of textbook records read from the file
*
* @return the number of textbook records read
*/
int read (string filename, Book books[]);
/**
* @param id the ISBN number to search for
* @param books[] the list of textbook records
* @param length the number of textbook records in the array
*
* @return the array index of the matching record, otherwise it returns -1
*/
int find (string id, Book books[], int length);
#endif /* BOOK_H */
```

condensed Code

```
e
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;
const int MAX_AUTHORS = 20;
struct Book {
string title;
string authors[MAX_AUTHORS];
short authorCount;
 string publisher;
 short yearPublish;
 bool hardcover;
 float price;
 string isbn;
 long copies;
};
int read (string filename, Book books[])
{
  ifstream inputFile(filename);
  //validation for the file itself
  if(!inputFile)
  {
    cout << "File does not exist!" << endl;
  }
  //use a mix of get line and ifstream
  //created a temporary string to consume lines
  //from primitive data types
  int counter =0;
  string consume_line;

  while(counter < 35 && getline(inputFile, books[counter].title))
  {
    inputFile >> books[counter].authorCount;
    getline(inputFile, consume_line);
     for(int j =0; j < books[counter].authorCount; j++)
      {
           getline(inputFile, books[counter].authors[j]);
       }
    getline(inputFile, books[counter].publisher);
    inputFile >> books[counter].yearPublish;
    inputFile >> books[counter].hardcover;
    inputFile >> books[counter].price;
    getline(inputFile, consume_line);
    getline(inputFile, books[counter].isbn);
    inputFile >> books[counter].copies;
    getline(inputFile, consume_line);
    if(inputFile.eof())
    {
      break;
    }
    counter++;
  }

   return counter;
}
int find(string id, Book books[], int length) 
{
  int found=0;
  for(int index = 0; index < length; index++)
  {
    string test =books[index].isbn;
    if(id.compare(test)==0)
    {
      found = index;

      break;
    }
    if(id > test)
    {
      cout << "greater than" << endl;
      found = -1;
      break;
    }
    if(id < test)
    {
      cout << "less than" << endl;
      found =-1;
      break;

    }

  }
  return found;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  //The structure of the book will also incorporate an array to
  //acommadate more books
    Book books[35];
    string filename = "test3.txt";
    string isbn = "0-201-60464-7";
    int filesRead = read (filename, books);

    int book_index = find(isbn, books, filesRead);
    if(book_index < 0)
    {
        cout << "Not found" << endl;
    }
    cout << books[book_index].title << endl;
    cout << books[book_index].authorCount<< endl;
    for(int j =0; j < books[book_index].authorCount; j++)
    {
       cout << books[book_index].authors[j];
    }
   cout << books[book_index].publisher <<endl;
   cout << books[book_index].yearPublish <<endl;
   cout << books[book_index].hardcover << endl;
   cout << books[book_index].price << endl;
   cout << books[book_index].isbn << endl;
   cout << books[book_index].copies << endl;
  }
```

test file in txt or dat whichever extension preferred 
@file.txt

```
C++ Network Programming – Volume 1
2
Douglas C. Schmidt
Stephen D. Huston
Addison-Wesley
2002
0
35.99
0-201-60464-7
236
```

Comment: can you reduce the code down to one specific comparison of one specific book record, with all values hard-coded (i.e. no need for multiple compilation units, no need for command line arguments, no need for an input file). hint: use a istringstream to simulate the input file.

Comment: Will do! sorry about that.

Comment: No worries. I see you're new here. You'll find that people are much more willing to help you if they can copy/paste your code directly into one file in an IDE and compile it.
The other advantage of breaking down the code this way is that you have a very good chance of identifying the bug yourself ;-)

Comment: Edited the code! Hopefully it is to your liking, but i tried hard coding as much as i could

Comment: I'll take a look.

Comment: Thanks! im still getting used to navigating c++ documentation!

Comment: I believe there is something wrong with the `for` loop in your `find()` function. I.e. the logic is broken - it's not the issue with string compare.

Comment: You should debug your `find()` function step-wise to see what I mean. Please, think (again) specifically about the `break`s which are in the 2nd and 3rd `if` inside of loop. (I assume you intended to do a `continue` instead.)

Comment: Ahh I see, but my main concern was also the comparison within the for loop. Does the isbn seem to equate to the book's isbn? i still am unable to properly equate the two.

Comment: Problem wasn't with `find`, at least for the minimal example. The code to read in the records was not correct. See answer.

Comment: The find loop will stop after only 1 iteration due to the break statement. It should be replaced by continue.

Answer (score 0):

- refactored to one compilation unit and zero test files.
- Fixed logic errors
- added some (hopefully explanatory) comments
- added handling of windows-style line endings for increased portability

Note: Avoid the use of `using namespace` at global scope. A reasonable exception to this rule is `using namespace std::literals;`

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
#include<cstring>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;
const int MAX_AUTHORS = 20;
struct Book {
string title;
string authors[MAX_AUTHORS];
short authorCount;
 string publisher;
 short yearPublish;
 bool hardcover;
 float price;
 string isbn;
 long copies;
};

void strip(std::string& str)
{
    if (str.size() && str.back() == '\r')
    {
        str.pop_back();
    }
}

std::istream& get_line_and_strip(std::istream& is, std::string& result)
{
    std::getline(is, result);
    strip(result);
    return is;
}

// be specific about the bounds of the output variable.
int read (std::istream& inputFile, Book books[35])
{
  //validation for the file itself
  if(!inputFile)
  {
    std::cout << "File does not exist!" << std::endl;
    // avoid UB by returning a value as per the function signature
    return 0;
  }

  //use a mix of get line and ifstream
  //created a temporary string to consume lines
  //from primitive data types
  int counter =0;
  std::string consume_line;

  while(counter < 35)
  {
    get_line_and_strip(inputFile, books[counter].title);
    inputFile >> books[counter].authorCount;
    std::getline(inputFile, consume_line);
    for(int j =0; j < books[counter].authorCount; j++)
    {
        get_line_and_strip(inputFile, books[counter].authors[j]);
    }
    get_line_and_strip(inputFile, books[counter].publisher);
    inputFile >> books[counter].yearPublish;
    std::getline(inputFile, consume_line);
    inputFile >> books[counter].hardcover;
    std::getline(inputFile, consume_line);
    inputFile >> books[counter].price;
    std::getline(inputFile, consume_line);
    get_line_and_strip(inputFile, books[counter].isbn);
    inputFile >> books[counter].copies;
    std::getline(inputFile, consume_line);
    if(!inputFile) // tests for EOF or error during input
    {
      break;
    }
    counter++;
  }

   return counter;
}
int find(string id, Book books[35], int length) 
{
  int found=0;
  for(int index = 0; index < length; index++)
  {
    string test =books[index].isbn;
    if(id.compare(test)==0)
    {
      found = index;

      break;
    }
    if(id > test)
    {
      cout << "greater than" << endl;
      found = -1;
      break;
    }
    if(id < test)
    {
      cout << "less than" << endl;
      found =-1;
      break;

    }

  }
  return found;
}

auto test_data = ""
"C++ Network Programming – Volume 1\r\n"
"2\r\n"
"Douglas C. Schmidt\r\n"
"Stephen D. Huston\r\n"
"Addison-Wesley\r\n"
"2002\r\n"
"0\r\n"
"35.99\r\n"
"0-201-60464-7\r\n"
"236\r\n"
""s;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    //The structure of the book will also incorporate an array to
    //acommadate more books
    Book books[35];
    string filename = "test3.txt";
    string isbn = "0-201-60464-7";
    auto test_file = std::istringstream(test_data);
    int filesRead = read (test_file, books);

    int book_index = find(isbn, books, filesRead);
    if(book_index < 0)
    {
        cout << "Not found" << endl;
        // would be invalid to continue if book not found
        return 0;
    }
    cout << books[book_index].title << endl;
    cout << books[book_index].authorCount<< endl;
    for(int j =0; j < books[book_index].authorCount; j++)
    {
        cout << books[book_index].authors[j] <<endl;
    }
    cout << books[book_index].publisher <<endl;
    cout << books[book_index].yearPublish <<endl;
    cout << books[book_index].hardcover << endl;
    cout << books[book_index].price << endl;
    cout << books[book_index].isbn << endl;
    cout << books[book_index].copies << endl;
}
```

Expected output:

```
C++ Network Programming – Volume 1
2
Douglas C. Schmidt
Stephen D. Huston
Addison-Wesley
2002
0
35.99
0-201-60464-7
236
```

https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9b08598ffcd0edc2

Comment: Thank you so much for the tips! Would this return carriage issue be due to windows? Could i use .ignore() instead of my fake consume line to remedy this?

Comment: Yes and no. Windows text files terminate lines with CRLF whereas linux/unix terminates with LF. `.ignore` can be used to replace the use of `std::getline(inputFile, consume_line)` and is marginally more efficient. Both `.ignore` and `getline` terminate on the LF by default so the CR is consumed (and added to the resulting string in Windows).

Comment: BTW if you find the answer helpful, it's customary to upvote it (click on the little up triangle). If the answer is unhelpful or wrong, you can downvote.